# MFC C++ WebBrowser Control load HTML from a string

Tags: c++, html, mfc, browser

I understand how to use the WebBrowser control to navigate to a page online:

```
m_browser.Navigate("www.microsoft.com", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

But what if I want to load in a string of HTML to display on the web browser? Is that doable? Or do I need to make a temporary html file locally and just navigate to that?

I appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can:

1. If you are using HTML View Control then you might use DTM_ADDTEXT message to add HTML string, and later DTM_ENDOFSOURCE to inform that all data was added.
2. Use write() from IHTMLDocument2 interface, as in following example: http://www.nuonsoft.com/blog/2010/03/24/how-to-use-the-microsoft-webbrowser-control-to-render-html-from-memory/
3. Load HTML content from Stream: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa752047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
4. Put your html file into temporary file on disk and then navigate to it (as your suggested I see)

Comment: Thank you ! Loading it from a stream is exactly what I want